# Is there a way to use radix-ui/colors variables in a css module file?

Tags: css, next.js, import, bundle, radix

I'm using next for a personal project and I'm trying to use Radix components along with radix-ui/colors.

Importing the color variables into the CSS Module creates an error, because the :root selector is suposed to be used in the _app file; importing the colors from the global stylesheet, however, doesn't affect the component.module.css files. It simply won't read the variables values.

content of the globals.css file

```
@import '../../node_modules/@radix-ui/colors/blackA.css';
@import '../../node_modules/@radix-ui/colors/green.css';
@import '../../node_modules/@radix-ui/colors/mauve.css';
@import '../../node_modules/@radix-ui/colors/violet.css';
@import '../../node_modules/@radix-ui/colors/whiteA.css';
```

content of the _app file

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import NiceModal from '@ebay/nice-modal-react'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <NiceModal.Provider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </NiceModal.Provider>
  )
}
```

Is there a way to use the color variables using nextjs and vanilla css, or do I have to go for the styled-components / stiches approach presented in Radix docs?

Tried importing variables directly into the module.css files, causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you import the colour scales you wish to use in `globals.css`, you'll then have access to the vanilla css variables globally throughout any of your css modules. If you wanted to use the colours in a custom `Button.js` component for example (excuse me not using Typescript):

globals.css:

```
@import "@radix-ui/colors/blue";

/* any other global styles... */
```

_app.js:

```
import "@/styles/globals.css";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};
```

button.module.scss:

```
.btn {
    color: var(--blue3);
    background: var(--blue9);
}
```

Button.js:

```
import styles from "@/styles/button.module.scss";

export default function Button (props) {
    return (
        <button className={styles.btn}>
            {props.children}
        </button>
    );
};
```

---

If you'd rather use them as Sass variables, you can create a partial which maps each CSS variable to a Sass variable and import that into any modules you like

_colours.scss:

```
$accent1: var(--blue1);
$accent2: var(--blue2);
$accent3: var(--blue3);
...
```

button.module.scss:

```
@use "./colours";

.btn {
    color: colours.$accent3;
    background: colours.$accent9;
}
```